# Does V8 monitor the execution of optimized machine code?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, v8, jit, execution

AFAIK, there are roughly two kinds of code objects in V8. One is javascript bytecode interpreted by Ignition, and the other is machine code which is compiled & optimized by Turbofan. According to the [execution/frames.h](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:v8/src/execution/frames.h), V8 constructs a different stackframe for each kind of code object. It means V8 should know the kind of the `callee` before it executes.

When unoptimized code(JS Bytecode) calls the optimized one, I guess that Ignition could handle the case properly to build a new stackframe for an optimized one. However, when the optimized code(machine code) calls the unoptimized one, I'm curious about how V8 determines whether `callee` is unoptimized or not. If the machine code is run directly on the processor, nothing can help V8 determine the kind of `callee`.

Also, in my understanding, V8 should detect whether some code dependency is compromised to mark or deoptimize the invalidated code objects. It also seems infeasible if V8 doesn't monitor the execution of machine code.

So my question is:

1. Does V8 monitor the execution of (optimized) machine code? If so, how does it happen?
2. If `1` is false, then how does V8 check the invalidation of code dependency or detect whether the `callee` is compiled or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "monitor"?

Comment: "*nothing can help V8 determine the kind of callee before executing the call instruction.*" - why would it need to? Setting up the new stack frame is the job of the called function (or possibly of `call` itself), it doesn't need to happen before the `call` instruction is executed.

Comment: @Bergi You mean `callee` build stackframe itself? Then is machine code calling unoptimized code the same as asking Ignition to interpret the target code object?

Comment: What is “invalid code dependency”?

Comment: @user2864740 As I know, Turbofan installs dependency into code object during the compilation.(see DependencyGroup@[code.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/3f63baf61e3eb70d3a607d7e3ee653fd496fbc88/src/objects/code.h)). If one of dependency is broken(invalidated), the code is deoptimized or would be deoptimized.

Comment: @Bergi I mean execution monitoring literally. If V8 doesn't monitor the execution of machine code, how does V8 detects the invalidation of some code dependencies while executing it? 
For example, let's see [test/mjsunit/compiler/deopt-lazy-shape-mutation.js](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/test/mjsunit/compiler/deopt-lazy-shape-mutation.js), and suppose `change_o` is optimized, then how v8 knows `f` should be deoptimized when returns to it.

Comment: The conversion of the frame seems to be done [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/deoptimizer/deoptimizer.cc;l=1001), so tracing back from there one might find the trampoline / exit that transforms the call

Comment: @SeungwanKwon you might be interested in [these slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Z6oCocRASCfTqGq1GCo1jbULDGS-w-nzxkbVF7Up0u0/edit#slide=id.g19fe2e08ca_0_259) which cover exactly that example in detail ;) (Though it is outdated, it still gives some overview on the concept of live patching)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> V8 constructs a different stackframe for each kind of code object. It means V8 should know the kind of the callee before it executes.

Stack frames are set up by whoever needs them, so callers don't have to inspect callees. (They could, if they had to.)

> If the machine code is run directly on the processor, nothing can help V8 determine the kind of callee.

V8 could emit machine code that checks the kind of callee. But to repeat myself: knowing the optimization status of a callee isn't necessary.

> Does V8 monitor the execution of (optimized) machine code?

No, it doesn't.

> how does V8 check the invalidation of code dependency

Dependencies are installed on something that can change (e.g. maps, protectors). When that change happens, registered code dependencies will be deoptimized (i.e. marked for "lazy deoptimization" when they have activations on the stack, or simply thrown away otherwise).

> [how does V8] detect whether the callee is compiled or not?

It doesn't need to. When a function isn't compiled yet, its "code" will be a stub that triggers compilation.

Comment: So in some way it is "monitored", as deoptimization will [scan the stack](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ELgd71B6iBaU6UmZ_lvwxf_OrYYnv0e4nuzZpK05-pg/edit) for invalidated functions, right?

Comment: What is "*marked for "lazy deoptimization"*", does that work like lazy compilation in reverse? Ie have their code replaced by a stub that converts the stack frame and calls into the interpreter?

Comment: @JonasWilms: I wouldn't call that "monitoring", but if you want to call it that, fine. -- Bergi: essentially yes. See the document that Jonas just linked for details. A key point is that "lazy deopt" is only done for non-topmost activations on the stack (the topmost, i.e. currently executing, function would just do an "eager deopt").

Comment: Ah, already found it myself: [yes it does](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Z6oCocRASCfTqGq1GCo1jbULDGS-w-nzxkbVF7Up0u0/edit#slide=id.g19fe2e08ca_0_286) Thanks @JonasWilms

Comment: @jmrk I wouldn't call that monitoring either, but the OP did, so I tried to link their thought chain to your answer ;)

Comment: Does deoptimizing a function also deoptimize all functions that call to it? Or how are these `call`s invalidated?

Comment: @JonasWilms: Deoptimizing a function doesn't affect its callers. Next time such a call is performed, it'll go to the unoptimized (or re-optimized) code for that function. You can think of it as function objects having an internal `.code` property which is reassigned as needed, and read by every call to that function. Of course, if a function got _inlined_ into its caller and needs to deopt, then there is only one combined code object to be thrown away -- that's one of the reasons why too much inlining can do more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks, that fills in the missing piece for me...

Comment: Thanks for kind answer. But what I don't understand yet is how V8 detects code dependency has been invalidated when machine code breaks it. 
Suppose function A and B is both compiled and A calls B. If B invalidates the dependency of A, how V8 mark A to be deoptimized before B returns?

Comment: In the example, `o` is initially assumed to be constant and annotated as such. When `f` is optimized and bakes in the assumption that `o` is constant, it is registered as a dependency of `o`. When `change_o` reassigns `o`, it sees that `o` is assumed-constant so far, so it marks all its dependencies for deoptimization, and marks `o` as non-constant. `f`'s lazy deopt will happen as soon as `change_o` returns (i.e. when `f` becomes the topmost stackframe). Put differently: B itself marks A for deoptimization; there isn't any third entity that has to watch what B is doing.

Comment: @jmrk So, compiled `change_o` checks how `o` is used in the context of `v8` before it changes, and mark every code object depending on shape of `o`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To look at the concrete example you gave in the comments:

```js
var b = false;

function change_o() {
  // as long as b is false, this won't be reassigned ...
  if (b) o = { y : 1, x : 0};
}

var o = { x : 1 };

function f() {
  change_o();
  // ... and thus o.x can be compiled down
  return o.x;
}

// f and change_o are compiled somewhen 
f(); f(); f(); // ...

// a precondition changes
b = true;

// during execution of change_o o is reassigned and changes its shape, accessing o.x will now need a different offset and thus f (which is currently on the stack) becomes invalid
f();
```

Thus at the moment the assignment `o =` happens, the runtime jumps into some deoptimization logic, which has to invalidate all the code based on the false assumption. Invalidating calls from non-compiled code to compiled code is easy, simply remove the reference to the compiled code from some kind of registry and nobobdy will call it anymore. Invalidating future calls from compiled functions to the invalidated compiled function is harder, though if the call uses some indirection, this indirection can be rewritten to redirect all future calls.
This leaves two kind of invalidation problems:

- the currently evaluated function needs to be invalidated (-> eager deoptimization), not that problematic either as it's the function that bailed out to the deoptimization routine
- a function that called the evaluated function needs to be invalidated (-> lazy deoptimization), this is problematic, as they might be somewhere in the stack, and continuing execution would somewhen resume to them (e.g. `f` in the example above)

However in the later case, there is a way to find and replace those functions:
Every time one function `call`s to another, it pushes the return address onto the stack (see e.g. [x86 stack usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=msvc-170)), and when the called function executes the `ret` instruction, it pops the address und jumps there. Thus by scanning the stack for return addresses residing inside invalidated functions, and replacing those by another address, when the inner function like `change_o` returns to `f`, it doesn't actually jump back to the compiled `f` code but into a handler, which can then make the necessary adjustments.

So V8 does not "monitor" the execution, it actively modifies it when necessary by rewriting the stack.

A detailed walkthrough can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ELgd71B6iBaU6UmZ_lvwxf_OrYYnv0e4nuzZpK05-pg/edit).